# How does parentheses grouping affect regular expression results?

Tags: ruby, regex

My regular expression should match any sequence of `a`, `b`, `c`, or `d`, or the character `x`; the string `"abcdxabcd"` should have three separate matches `"abcd"`, `"x"`, and `"abcd"`.

I do not understand the differences between the following regular expressions, and am looking for a detailed explanation of how the parentheses are affecting the results. For test string `"abcdxabcd"`:

1. `/[abcd]+|x/` This one seems to work. The next four don't.
2. `/(d|[abc])+|x/` Returns three match groups {d}, {[empty]}, and {d}
3. `/(d|[abc]+)+|x/` Returns three match groups {d}, {[empty]}, and {d}
4. `/(d|[abc]+)+|(x)/` Returns three match groups {d, [empty]}, {[empty],x}, and {d,[empty]}
5. `/((d|[abc]+)+|(x))/` Returns three match groups {abcd, d, [empty]}, {x,[empty],x}, and {abcd, d, [empty]}

I'm not exactly familiar with the concept of a match group, which is part of my question here. My goal here is not to find a working expression so much as to understand the differences between these cases and understand what the ones that don't work are actually doing.

Comment: Can you show some of your test cases? Why don't the last four work (i.e., what do/don't they match that the first one does)? At first glance they should — in any case they match your string `"abcdxabcd"`.

Comment: any set of characters from a-d should all be part of one match.  the character x should be part of another match.  any other characters that appear should not match.

Comment: Are you using `String#scan` to get these matches?

Comment: I am going to use `String#scan` in my code eventually to parse the string, but for now I am just using Rubular to make sure it will work.

Comment: Ah yes, like you said earlier. Ok. It looks like Rubular uses `scan` or something similar.

Comment: How many matches should "abcdabc" have, one or four?

Comment: It should only count as 1 match - all one uninterrupted sequence.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

========= `/[abcd]+|x/`

This definitely works, this expression matches either `[abcd]+` OR `|` matches a `x`. `[abcd]+` matches one or more combinations of the letters `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`. `x` matches a literal `x`.

So when you run it against `abcdxabcd`, `[abcd]+` first matches `abcd`, then `x` matches that literal `x` then `[abcd]+` matches the second `abcd`.

Now you are totally correct, those are separate matches, in other words, if you were to use `/^[abcd]+|x$/` as the regular expression *(notice the anchors `^` and `$`)* you would notice that this wouldn't match `abcdxabcd`.

========= `/(d|[abc])+|x/`

This is a totally different expression. `(d|[abc])+` matches either a `d` or `[abc]` and captures whatever matches inside capturing group number 1, but this expression is repeated one or more times because of `+` so the capturing group contains the last thing that was matched by what is inside of it.

So when you run this against `abcdxabcd`, `a` is matched by `[abc]` then `b` too, then `c` too, but then `d` is matched by `d` and this is the last thing that is matched by the entire group `(d|[abc])+` so `d` is the value matched by the group and hence match group 1 which is `d`.

Now comes the `x` which is matched by `x` and the group didn't capture anything so the second capturing group is an empty one.

Now the final capturing group work the same way the first one does, so we get: `{d}`, `{}` and `{d}`.

I could go on and explain the rest of the expressions one by one, but this would take a lot of typing. I hope you can see how this works for the rest of them.

**Summary:** When a group doesn't match, it captures the empty string *(I don't know if this actually happens in Ruby code, or it is just displayed by Rubular for clarity)*. The last thing that is captured by a certain group is what stays on, and the previous captures are gone if that group matches many times.

**EDIT:** A capturing group simply captures or remembers what the expression inside it has matched, so you can refer to it either in the regular expression itself via back references or refer to it in the replacement string.

aha I forgot to tell you that capturing groups are numbered starting with 1, and are counted from left to right.

Let me show you an example: if you want to match a character that is repeated immediately after itself you can use:

```
(.)\1
```

the `.` matches a single character, `()` capture what was matched in group 1, then we try to match the same thing that was matched by group 1 using `\1` which is called a back reference.

Another example: Let's say you want to match one more characters that are separated by dashes, something like this: `abc-53` and you want to reference them in a replacement string.

You would match with:

```
([^-]+)-([^-]+)
```

`([^-]+)` matches one or more characters that are not dashes `-`, now we use what was captured in a replacement string like this:

```
$2 == $1
```

This will result into converting `abc-53` into `53 == abc`.

The subject of capturing groups and other regular expression features may require a lot of explanation, you can check [regular-expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info) for more information.

Comment: Can you flesh out the details of what exactly a capture group is and how they work?